# SWIFT - Nested enums

Tags: ios, swift, enums

At the moment I'm working with enums where I need in some object store different enum cases but I want to avoid doing switch statement in every implementation. In my custom object Im saving his type from enum "**CarModType**" where I have specified more subTypes as "**Engine, Interior, Exterior...**". So I can store in my object that this current object is type "**Interior.Seats**" and I don't need work with my "type" variability which is `var type: PostProcessingFramework.CarModType?` in order to store different enums for CarModType e.g "**Engine, Exterior, Interior**". My enums seems like this:

```
public enum CarModType {
        case interior(Interior)
        case exterior(Exterior)
        case engine(Engine)
        case driveTrain(DriveTrain)
        case suspension(Suspension)
        case steering(Steering)
        case brakes(Brakes)
        case extra(Extra) 

    enum Interior: String,CaseIterable {
            
            case steering = "interior.steering"
            case seats = "interior.seats"
            case shiftSystem = "interior.shiftSystem"
            case pedals = "interior.pedals"
            case accessories = "interior.accessories"
            case centralUnit = "interior.centralUnit"
            case extra = "interior.extra"
            
            
            class stored {
                static let array:[PostProcessingFramework.CarModType.Interior] = [.accessories,.centralUnit,.extra,.pedals,.seats,.shiftSystem,.steering]
            }

            static func returnTitle(category: PostProcessingFramework.CarModType.Interior) -> String {
                switch category {
                case .steering:
                    return "Steering"
                case .seats:
                    return "Seats"
                case .shiftSystem:
                    return "Shift System"
                case .pedals:
                    return "Pedals"
                case .accessories:
                    return "Accessories"
                case .centralUnit:
                    return "Central Unit"
                case .extra:
                    return "Extra"
                }
            }
        }
```

Then I was facing other problem, because of my DB I'm saving this type in his rawValue as I have specified in subTypes. Cuz of that, I came up with some functions which will transform all enum cases into an dictionary and then I can by accessing this dictionary with key as rawValue of nested Enum (subType) get a specific "**Type**" (e.g CarModType.Engine(.cylinderHead)) from rawValue. My functions:

```
static func returnType(rawValue: String) -> CarModType? {
     let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
     let dictionaries = [
         Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: CarModType.Interior.allCases.map{ (CarModType.interior($0).stringValue,CarModType.interior($0)) }),
         Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: CarModType.Exterior.allCases.map{ (CarModType.exterior($0).stringValue,CarModType.exterior($0)) }),
         Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: CarModType.Engine.allCases.map{ (CarModType.engine($0).stringValue,CarModType.engine($0)) })
     ]
     var dict = [String:CarModType]()
     var i = 0
     for subDict in dictionaries {
         dict.merge(subDict){(_, curr) in curr }
         i += 1
         if i == dictionaries.count {
             semaphore.signal()
         }
     }
     semaphore.wait()
     if let val = dict[rawValue] {
         return val
     } else {
        return nil
     }
 }

 var stringValue: String {
     switch self {
         
     case let .interior(subtype):
         if let type = PostProcessingFramework.CarModType.Interior.init(rawValue: subtype.rawValue) {
             return type.rawValue
         } else {
             return ""
         }
     case let .exterior(subtype):
         if let type = PostProcessingFramework.CarModType.Exterior.init(rawValue: subtype.rawValue) {
             return type.rawValue
         } else {
             return ""
         }
      case let .engine(subtype):
         if let type = PostProcessingFramework.CarModType.Engine.init(rawValue: subtype.rawValue) {
             return type.rawValue
         } else {
             return ""
         }
    }
}
```

Isn't out there some better, more "elegant" way to have done this ? Thank you very much for answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all raw values are unique, like they seem to be for `Interior` with the namespace like string, you can add an `init` at the top level that goes through and tries to create an instance of each sub type until it succeeds

Here is an example for the 2 first case elements

```
init?(asRaw: String) {
    if let item = Interior(rawValue: asRaw) {
        self = CarModType.interior(item)
    } else if let item = Exterior(rawValue: asRaw) {
        self = CarModType.exterior(item)
    //... rest of case items here
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there any way we could avoid a long if let block? (in case there is a large number of sub types? eg: 20)

Comment: @MaheshDeSilva Hard to say without more information but you must somehow match each possible value with a type.